# WIX Project cannot load with pre-build-event specified

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix

After much trouble I have a heat.exe command string that should run and put the files of a folder into a WXS file.

It looks like this

```
heat dir "$(var.SolutionDir)Web\obj\$(var.MyProject.Configuration)Package" -gg -g1 -cg PACKAGEFILES sreg -dr DEPLOYFOLDER -var "$(var.SolutionDir)Web\obj\$(var.MyProject.Configuration)Package" -out "$(var.SolutionDir)WebInstaller\PackageFragment.wxs"
```

I used this to get it: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2010/02/23/WiX-3-Tutorial-Generating-filedirectory-fragments-with-Heat.exe.aspx

However when I try to copy that into my pre-build-event box under "Properties->Build Events" for my WIX project in VS2010 - VS2010 crashes and I cannot load my project until I delete the command directly from the project file xml code.

I now have two questions:

1. Is this command string correct?
2. Why does my project crash like that?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project crashes because Visual Studio attempts to interpret the `$(stuff)` as MSBuild properties and gets all confused and crashes.

You'll want to convert that command-line to MSBuild syntax by directly editing the .wixproj file. That way you bypass the parsing code in Visual Studio that crashes.  Something like:

```
<Exec Command='heat dir "..\Web\obj\$(Configuration)Package" -gg -g1 -cg PACKAGEFILES sreg -dr DEPLOYFOLDER -var "..\Web\obj\$(Configuration)Package" -out "..\WebInstaller\PackageFragment.wxs"'
```

Note: $(var.SolutionDir) is only available when building inside Visual Studio so I recommend not using it (in the example above, I made it a relative path).

Comment: Would it make sense to add a Heat command attribute to the fragment element so it would create itself at compile time?

Comment: No because the compile phase doesn't touch the disk today.